# Casting an untyped code quotation?

Tags: f#, quotations, type-providers

In the MiniCsvTypeProvider, I see the following line of code:

```
        let prop = ProvidedProperty(fieldName, fieldTy, GetterCode = fun [row] -> <@@ (%%row:float[]).[i] @@>)
```

with GetterCode type is : *Quotations.Expr list -> Quotations.Expr* :

I don't really know what the lambda **fun** is doing....

- it matches its input with a single element array, binding it to a variable named 'row' , of type Quotations.Expr from the GetterCode signature.
- it creates a code quotation in return
- inside the code quotation, it uses %%row:float[] and I don't know what this means : **is that a Float [] type constraint for  untyped code quotations  ?**

Comment: sort of. In msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233212.aspx): you use the %% operator to insert an untyped expression object into an untyped quotation.

Comment: i saw that, but what puzzles me is more the ":float[]" part. Edited the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jack's answer is correct.  I'll add a bit more context. `(%%)` is the untyped splice operator (that is, it splices a `Quotations.Expr` into another typed or untyped quotation), while `(%)` is the typed splice operator (that is, it splices a `Quotations.Expr<'t>` for some `'t` into another typed or untyped quotation).  `(a : ty)` is just a type annotation, so `(%%row : float[])` indicates that when `row` is spliced into the quotation the result is a `float[]`.  Without this annotation, `%%row` could be a value of any type, and the compiler would be unable to infer what we mean by the `.[]` indexer (just as it can't infer the type of `arr` in `fun arr i -> arr.[i]`).

In case it's helpful, here are some alternative ways to express roughly the same thing as `<@@ (%%row:float[]).[i] @@>`:

- We can convert the untyped quotation to a typed quotation before splicing:

  ```
  let typedRow = Quotations.Expr.Cast<float[]> row 
  <@@ %typedRow.[i] @@>
  ```

  Here we are using the typed splice operator `(%)`, so the compiler knows that `%typedRow` is a `float[]` and that the `.[]` operator is applicable.
- We can use a different way of indexing into the array so that F#'s type inference can determine the type of `%%row` without an annotation:

  ```
  <@@ Array.get %%row i : float @@>
  ```

  Here, the `Array.get` method takes an `'a[]` as an argument and we add a type annotation which indicates that the result is a float, so F# will infer that `%%row` is a `float[]`.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. Code quotation leaves some leeway to blow your mind it seems. unfortunately in the prog considered, the expression goes through a specific 'evaluator' whose capacities are limited. for instance doing this does not work,  : ProvidedProperty(fieldName, fieldTy, GetterCode = fun [row] -> <@@ ReflectiveBuilder.BuildTypedCast fieldTy ((%%row:obj[]).[i])  @@>)

Answer (score 2):

The :float[] is an explicit type annotation (not constraint, which is similar but different); it's saying %%row will produce a value of type float[].

Then by wrapping it in parenthesis, you can use the .[idx] syntax to get an element of the array because the F# compiler infers the type of the value within the parenthesis as float[].

Explicitly specifying a type annotation this way can be a useful way to give the F# compiler a "hint" and resolve type inference errors.

Comment: indeed. I was confused by the new to me code quotation syntax. thank you.